# Mixing Twilio video with conference obects

Tags: webrtc, twilio

Twilio video allows multiple WebRTC endpoints to participate in a *conversation*, and there's also the *conference* object that allows Twilio VoIP clients to mix with PSTN callers.  What I'm trying to figure out is whether there's a way to bridge the two types of entity together, by adding the audio from a PSTN caller to a video conversation among WebRTC endpoints.

Any idea as to whether this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is not currently possible with [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/video), however if you just want audio conferences then you can achieve this with [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/client). Twilio Client uses WebRTC in the browser and connects to other calls in the same way that a phone call through Twilio works.

Check out this [tutorial that builds an app with browser to browser and browser to phone calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/browser-calls/php/laravel) to get started with Twilio Client.

Comment: Thanks, Phil.  I also heard this from product management.  We can probably live with this for now, with the expectation that this is addressed in the product roadmap.